# Insertar solo Datos Nuevos de una tabla temporal a otra tabla mediante Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Buen dia
quisiera saber la forma correcta de pasar datos nuevos de una tabla temporal a otra tabla.
La Tabla Temporal Contiene Datos nuevos que es la tabla de abajo

Quisiera que solo los datos nuevos de la tabla temporal pasaran ala tabla Balanzas.
E estado pensado en inner join pero aun no pruebo

[image]

Comment: as intentado un `insert into balanzas select * from #balanzaTempTable where cuenta='101-000'`

Comment: No me serviria ya que el where cuenta='101-000' es dinamico ,el numero de cuenta varia

Comment: cambias la condicion a fecha?

Comment: los datos de la tabla temporal los obtengo de un Bulk Insert Y de esa tabla selecciona los datos nuevos y los inserta la tabla balanzas ,eso es lo que tengo pensado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en mi opinion el uso de la tabla temporal deberia ser que solo tengas datos en cierta accion, una vez dejada la accion los datos de la temporal pasarian directamente a la tabla master y la temporal deberias borrarla, para que no te ocupe espacios

Comment: Si , de hecho en el store procedure primero se inserta en la tabla temporal y después compara que nuevos datos tiene en comparación de la tabla base y al ultimo de elimina la tabla temp

Comment: teniendo en cuenta mi comentario anterior, al momento de tener datos en la temporal  son nuevos, no es necesario la comparacion para ver cuales son nuevos, si no solamente diferenciar los que se agregaron en la store procedure

Comment: ese es mi problema ya que si yo inserto 7000 datos  y solo 1 es nuevo me inserta los 7000, yo lo que quiero es que de alguna forma solo inserte ese dato nuevo

Comment: por eso en la imagen se ve por fechas ,por lo general solo se agrega un mes y año por store,cuando los datos nadamas traen una fecha se vuelve a insertar todo y eso es lo que no quiero,saludos

Comment: agrega un campo extra en la temporal, que sea el que diferencia el nuevo del resto, asi al pasar a la master solo hazla con la condiciion de que exista dicho campo

Comment: me gusta esa idea,agregaria esa columna ala tabla temporal y luego la eliminaria ?

Comment: hmm, esa columna yo diria que quedaria ahi en la temporal, su uso sería solamente para distinguir cuando entra un registro nuevo y ser diferenciado de las demas mientras que al pasar ya a la master, si la tabla temporal se borra bien, si no solo sería que ese registro que se pase a la master la columna nueva se limpie

Comment: Tiene lógica para mi, Gracias

Comment: de nada y un gusto ayudar a la comunidad

Saludos Coordiales